# Edit a .json file (add a new line with Linux command line)

Tags: json, linux

```
{
"layerOrder": [
    "Layer1",
    "Layer2",
    "Layer3",
    "Layer4"
    ]
}
```

This is target.json, I need to add a "Layer0" before "Layer1", by Linux command line.

```
{
"layerOrder": [
    "Layer0",
    "Layer1",
    "Layer2",
    "Layer3",
    "Layer4"
    ]
}
```

How can I do it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks like it would be relatively easy. Just read the file with whatever language you prefer and then modify it. What's stopping you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get the job done given what you have stated in the question, then this will work:

```
$ head json -n 2; echo -e "    \"Layer0\","; sed -n '3,$p' json > newjson
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -ie 's/"layerOrder": \[/"layerOrder": \[ \n\t\t"Layer0",/' file.json
```

I found this approach, the main problem was with special symbols ([)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a robust and/or flexible solution, it would probably be better to use a JSON-aware tool, such as [jq](/questions/tagged/jq).  In conjunction with `sponge`, you could write:

```
< input.json jq --arg first Layer0 '.layerOrder |= [$first] + .' | sponge input.json
```

This is also portable between the C, Go, and Rust implementations of jq, i.e. jq, gojq, and jaq.